# Loop on files - Parse Files and group them by identifier

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, parsing, tibble

I would like to :

1. Read the list of * .bed files from the directory
2. For all the .bed files in my folder, I would like to use the information contained in all the rows *id=NAME*, part of the fifth column in all the *.bed files (e.g., Hox.bed and zinc.bed below)
3. Determine which family the given file belongs to (e.g `cram-2`) using a separate lookup table linking `id` values to a `Family` value (e.g., Lookup Table below)
4. Combine/concatenate all the files with the same family (e.g HOX.bed and zinc.bed) into one .bed file.
5. Save the linked file with the name of the column Family (e.g cram-2.bed).

Example:

**The HOX.bed file rows :**

```
ma  reg out fim id=HOX;seq=AGCAGGAAATA;score=12.1915;pval=4.97e-05
se  reg out fim id=HOX;seq=AGCAGGAAATA;score=12.1915;pval=4.97e-05
to  reg out fim id=HOX;seq=AGCAGGAAATA;score=12.1915;pval=4.97e-05
pa  reg out fim id=HOX;seq=AGCAGGAAATA;score=12.1915;pval=4.97e-05
```

**The zinc.bed file rows :**

```
ma  reg out fim id=zinc;seq=AGCAGGAAATA;score=12.1915;pval=4.97e-05
se  reg out fim id=zinc;seq=AGCAGGAAATA;score=12.1915;pval=4.97e-05
to  reg out fim id=zinc;seq=AGCAGGAAATA;score=12.1915;pval=4.97e-05
pa  reg out fim id=zinc;seq=AGCAGGAAATA;score=12.1915;pval=4.97e-05
```

**The lookup table :**

```
Name                        Family
HOX                         cram-2
zinc                        cram-2
fire                        sf.xr
fire                        ra.XS-2
...continues...
```

**the output I search to obtain :**

File name =  cram-2.bed

Concatenate HOX.bed and zinc.bed because both are from Family cram-2!

```
ma  reg out fim id=HOX;seq=AGCAGGAAATA;score=12.1915;pval=4.97e-05
se  reg out fim id=HOX;seq=AGCAGGAAATA;score=12.1915;pval=4.97e-05
to  reg out fim id=HOX;seq=AGCAGGAAATA;score=12.1915;pval=4.97e-05
pa  reg out fim id=HOX;seq=AGCAGGAAATA;score=12.1915;pval=4.97e-05
ma  reg out fim id=zinc;seq=AGCAGGAAATA;score=12.1915;pval=4.97e-05
se  reg out fim id=zinc;seq=AGCAGGAAATA;score=12.1915;pval=4.97e-05
to  reg out fim id=zinc;seq=AGCAGGAAATA;score=12.1915;pval=4.97e-05
pa  reg out fim id=zinc;seq=AGCAGGAAATA;score=12.1915;pval=4.97e-05
```

**I started to prepare a script structure but I am struggling in how to set up that all the files with same Family will have to end up in the same output file (.bed possibly)**

```
myFiles <- list.files(pattern = "\\.bed$") 
for(i in myFiles){
  name <- read.table((i), header = FALSE, sep="\t", stringsAsFactors=FALSE, quote="")
  name <- name %>% top_n(1, "id")
  Family_filtering <-
    table %>% filter(
      Family %in% name)
  save(...????????...)
}
```

Thank you a lot for the help!!!

Comment: What I write is a bit confusing. Write it clearer. Provide an example .bed file. Write specifically what data you want to read from it. Write down what you want to do with this data later. Save to file, process?

Comment: @MarekFiołka Here is it better I hope. Best

Comment: It is still unclear. Do you want this:
1. Read the list of * .bed files from the directory
2. Determine which family the given file belongs to (Family1, Family2 etc.)
3. Combine all files from one family into one text file?
3. Save the linked file as FamilyNr.bed?

Comment: @MarekFiołka Is now better? Best and thank you for your time!

Comment: @MarekFiołka I will try it as soon as possible and validate the answer! Thank you a lot! Really Helpful and understanding flow!

Comment: I would be grateful if your appreciation of my work was expressed in accepting the correct solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert each activity into one function and then combine it all together. Simple isn't it?!?

```
library(fs)
library(tidyverse)

dfNameFamily = tibble(
  Name = c("HOX", "zinc", "fire", "fire2"),
  Family = c("cram-2", "cram-2", "sf.xr", "ra.XS-2"))

dir = "bedfile"

BedFile = function(dir) dir_ls(dir, regexp = "\\.bed$")

readTxt = function(FileName){
  lines = character()
  if(file_exists(FileName)){
    con = file(FileName, open = "r")
    lines = readLines(con)
    close(con)
  }
  lines
}

GetName = function(l) str_match(l, "id=(.+);seq")[1,2]

SaveFile = function(l, name, dir){
  con = file(paste0(dir, "/" , name))
  writeLines(unlist(l$lines), con)
  close(con)
}

tibble(FileName = BedFile(dir)) %>%  #Read all bed file names
  mutate(
    lines = map(FileName, readTxt),  #Read all lines from any bed file
    Name = map_chr(lines, GetName)) %>%  #Get Name for eny bed file
  left_join(dfNameFamily, by="Name") %>%  #Join Family
  group_by(Family) %>%  
  group_walk(SaveFile, dir)  #Save Family file
```

Comment: Hi Marek Thank you a lot I will try it as soon as possible!

Comment: I'm glad I could help. Remember, however, that on Stack Overflow, you say thank you by selecting the approved solution.

Comment: Yes sure! I needed to try out the code, being on exam session couldn't in the immediate. Best

Comment: Does it help to add                                                                                           ""SaveFile = tempfile()"" if I am working on huge files?    ```tibble((FileName = TxtFile(dir)) %>%  
  mutate(
    lines = map(FileName, readTxt),  
    Name = map_chr(lines, GetName)) %>%  
  left_join(dfNameFamily, by="Name") %>%  
  group_by(Class) %>%  
  group_walk(SaveFile, dir),  
  SaveFile = tempfile())```

Comment: I don't think saving to the temporary file is going to help. My `SaveFile` function is based on `writeLines` which is definitely a very fast way to write to files. You just have to wait for the data to write to the disk. It is possible that there are other functions that make writing to the file even faster. Unfortunately, I have never tested it in R.

Comment: I tried on a small batch of files and it runs perfectly. But on the full dataset (1376 files for more than 140 Gbts) after 2 days it was still working without any out-put. It is already asking to read in all the files only the first row containing ```"id=(.+);seq"```..not all the rows..this should already fasten the process right?!

Comment: Well, it can actually be troublesome. Especially when it is not known at what stage the calculations are. Let's see what can be done about it. As I guess, this part of the `tibble (FileName = BedFile (dir))` part of the code should execute quickly. After this treatment, you can, for example, divide it into several smaller sets, e.g. using a `filter`, and carry out further mutation with reading and writing to the file only for this filtered part.

Comment: No no! This is not a good idea. For such a large number of files, it definitely has to be done differently. Give me a moment to think.

Comment: Thank you I will do it ! @MarekFiolka