# for nested loops performing slow with list of tibbles in R

Tags: r, performance, time-series, nested-loops, tibble

I have a list of 106 tibbles, which are time series, within data_sensor. Every tibble has two columns with Date and temperature respectively.

On the other hand I have a list of 106 dates in date_admin which contain the dates where I want my time series to end by tibble.

The code works properly but using the nested for-loop it takes too much time as the average number of rows is close to 10000th per tibble.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)

#List nesting all the dataframes of all the xls files
files <- dir("C:/User*inals", pattern = "\\.xls$", full.names = TRUE)
data_sensor <- lapply(files, read_xls)

##List nesting all the dataframes of all the xlsx files
filesx <- dir("C:/Us******ls", pattern = "\\.xlsx$", full.names = TRUE)
data_generic <- lapply(filesx, read_xlsx)

idxend=vector()
for (i in seq_along(data_sensor)){
  for (j in seq_along(data_sensor[[i]][[1]])){
    if (as.Date(data_sensor[[i]][[1]][[j]]) < as.Date(date_admin[i])){
      data_sensor[[i]][[1]][[j]] = data_sensor[[i]][[1]][[j]]
    } else{ #Convert all the elements after condition to NA's
        data_sensor[[i]][[1]][[j]] = NA
        data_sensor[[i]][[2]][[j]] = NA
    }
}
#Drop all NA's
for (i in seq_along(data_sensor)){
  data_sensor[[i]] = drop_na(data_sensor[[i]])
}
}
```

In order to clarify my list of tibbles and vector:

```
> data_sensor[[1]][[1]][[1]]
[1] "2018-08-07 11:00:31 UTC"
> data_sensor[[1]][[2]][[1]]
[1] 6.3
> data_sensor[[2]][[1]][[1]]
[1] "2018-08-08 11:56:05 UTC" 
#data_sensor[[index of list]][[column of tibble(date,Temperature)]][[row of tibble]]
> date_admin
  [1] "2018-10-07 UTC" "2018-12-29 UTC" "2018-12-13 UTC" "2019-08-09 UTC" "2019-10-10 UTC"
  [6] "2019-04-26 UTC" "2018-11-21 UTC" "2018-08-23 UTC" "2019-07-08 UTC" "2019-11-19 UTC"
 [11] "2019-11-07 UTC" "2018-09-05 UTC" "2018-09-03 UTC" "2018-09-24 UTC" "2018-10-11 UTC"
 [16] "2018-09-25 UTC" "2019-03-29 UTC" "2018-08-20 UTC" "2018-09-17 UTC" "2019-03-30 UTC"
 [21] "2018-11-07 UTC" "2019-01-01 UTC" "2018-08-31 UTC" "2019-03-27 UTC" "2019-11-10 UTC"
 [26] "2019-04-04 UTC" "2019-10-18 UTC" "2018-09-06 UTC" "2018-09-23 UTC" "2018-09-22 UTC"
 [31] "2019-07-22 UTC" "2018-09-04 UTC" "2019-05-17 UTC" "2018-11-05 UTC" "2018-12-09 UTC"
 [36] "2018-09-03 UTC" "2019-05-21 UTC" "2019-02-22 UTC" "2018-08-30 UTC" "2019-06-04 UTC"
 [41] "2018-09-13 UTC" "2018-10-14 UTC" "2019-11-08 UTC" "2018-08-30 UTC" "2019-04-12 UTC"
 [46] "2018-09-24 UTC" "2018-08-22 UTC" "2018-08-30 UTC" "2018-09-07 UTC" "2018-11-11 UTC"
 [51] "2018-11-01 UTC" "2018-10-01 UTC" "2018-10-22 UTC" "2018-12-03 UTC" "2019-06-06 UTC"
 [56] "2018-09-09 UTC" "2018-09-10 UTC" "2018-09-24 UTC" "2018-10-11 UTC" "2018-11-30 UTC"
 [61] "2018-09-20 UTC" "2019-11-20 UTC" "2018-10-11 UTC" "2018-10-09 UTC" "2018-09-27 UTC"
 [66] "2019-11-11 UTC" "2018-10-04 UTC" "2018-09-14 UTC" "2019-04-27 UTC" "2018-09-04 UTC"
 [71] "2018-09-11 UTC" "2018-08-14 UTC" "2018-09-01 UTC" "2018-10-01 UTC" "2018-09-25 UTC"
 [76] "2018-09-28 UTC" "2018-09-29 UTC" "2018-10-11 UTC" "2019-03-26 UTC" "2018-10-26 UTC"
 [81] "2018-11-21 UTC" "2018-12-02 UTC" "2018-09-08 UTC" "2019-01-08 UTC" "2018-11-07 UTC"
 [86] "2019-02-05 UTC" "2019-01-21 UTC" "2018-09-11 UTC" "2018-12-17 UTC" "2019-01-15 UTC"
 [91] "2018-08-28 UTC" "2019-01-08 UTC" "2019-05-14 UTC" "2019-01-21 UTC" "2018-11-12 UTC"
 [96] "2018-10-26 UTC" "2019-12-26 UTC" "2020-01-03 UTC" "2020-01-06 UTC" "2020-02-26 UTC"
[101] "2020-02-14 UTC" "2020-01-27 UTC" "2020-01-21 UTC" "2020-03-16 UTC" "2020-02-26 UTC"
[106] "2019-12-31 UTC"

data_sensor[[1]]
                   date Temperature
1   2018-08-07 11:00:31         6.3
2   2018-08-07 11:10:31        11.4
3   2018-08-07 11:20:31        12.0
4   2018-08-07 11:30:31        13.7
5   2018-08-07 11:40:31        15.6
6   2018-08-07 11:50:31        13.6
7   2018-08-07 12:00:31        12.2
8   2018-08-07 12:10:31        11.2
9   2018-08-07 12:20:31        11.6
...............................
...............................
...............................
499 2018-08-10 22:00:31         9.7
500 2018-08-10 22:10:31         9.6
 [ reached 'max' / getOption("max.print") -- omitted 8592 rows ]
```

It takes some minutes to clean the data through the nested for loops. How can I improve the performance of my code?

Error implementing answer:

```
    > data_sensor = 
+   tibble(
+     file = paste("file",1:length(date_admin)),
+     date_admin = date_admin
+   ) %>% 
+   mutate(data_sensor = map(file, ~data_sensor))

> data_sensor
# A tibble: 106 x 3
   file    date_admin          data_sensor 
   <chr>   <dttm>              <list>      
 1 file 1  2018-10-07 00:00:00 <list [106]>
 2 file 2  2018-12-29 00:00:00 <list [106]>
 3 file 3  2018-12-13 00:00:00 <list [106]>
```

The class of my data_sensor before implementing the code is a `list` and after it becomes:

`[1] "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"`

The error appears in that chunk:

```
> data_sensor = data_sensor %>% 
+   group_by(file) %>% 
+   group_modify(~f(.x))
 Error in UseMethod("mutate") : 
  no applicable method for 'mutate' applied to an object of class "list" 
> class(data_sensor)
[1] "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"
> data_sensor = data_sensor %>% 
+   group_by(file) %>% 
+   group_modify(~f(.x))
 Error in UseMethod("mutate") : 
  no applicable method for 'mutate' applied to an object of class "list"
```

Comment: You could try computing each inner loop in parallel with `foreach`. Here's an example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69362113/transform-lapply-to-foreach-with-dopar/69362972#69362972 and https://www.r-bloggers.com/2016/07/lets-be-faster-and-more-parallel-in-r-with-doparallel-package/

Comment: Thank you @Skaqqs. I am still checking how to make it work for my case but at some point I will use your suggestion for sure!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely don't do it in a loop !! There are much more efficient methods for such operations. I'll show you how to do it. But first I need to generate some data. For this, I created two little functions. `rndDate` randomizes the start date from "1/1/2018" to "12/31/2020", while `fDateSensor` returns `tibble` with a time series every 10 minutes.

```
rndDate = function(start_date=ymd("20180101"), end_date=ymd("20201231")){ 
  sample(seq(start_date, end_date, "days"), 1)}

fDateSensor = function(n) tibble(
    date = rndDate() + 1:n*dminutes(10),
    Temperature = rnorm(n)
  )

fDateSensor(5)
```

output

```
# A tibble: 5 x 2
  date                Temperature
  <dttm>                    <dbl>
1 2019-09-27 00:10:00      -0.511
2 2019-09-27 00:20:00       0.531
3 2019-09-27 00:30:00       1.42 
4 2019-09-27 00:40:00       0.252
5 2019-09-27 00:50:00      -0.570
```

Now I'm going to make a tibble with internal tibble. First, for two dates, `date_admin`.

```
nDateSensor = 10
set.seed(1234)
date_admin = c("2018-10-07", "2019-07-29")
data_sensor = 
  tibble(
    file = paste("file",1:length(date_admin)),
    date_admin = date_admin
  ) %>% 
  mutate(data_sensor = map(file, ~fDateSensor(nDateSensor)))
data_sensor
```

output

```
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  file   date_admin data_sensor      
  <chr>  <chr>      <list>           
1 file 1 2018-10-07 <tibble [10 x 2]>
2 file 2 2019-07-29 <tibble [10 x 2]>
```

As you can see, I simulated reading two files. Their content is in the variable `data_sensor` which is `tibble` of size 10x2.

```
data_sensor$data_sensor
[[1]]
# A tibble: 10 x 2
   date                Temperature
   <dttm>                    <dbl>
 1 2020-10-14 00:10:00      0.314 
 2 2020-10-14 00:20:00      0.359 
 3 2020-10-14 00:30:00     -0.730 
 4 2020-10-14 00:40:00      0.0357
 5 2020-10-14 00:50:00      0.113 
 6 2020-10-14 01:00:00      1.43  
 7 2020-10-14 01:10:00      0.983 
 8 2020-10-14 01:20:00     -0.622 
 9 2020-10-14 01:30:00     -0.732 
10 2020-10-14 01:40:00     -0.517 

[[2]]
# A tibble: 10 x 2
   date                Temperature
   <dttm>                    <dbl>
 1 2019-07-28 00:10:00     -0.776 
 2 2019-07-28 00:20:00      0.0645
 3 2019-07-28 00:30:00      0.959 
 4 2019-07-28 00:40:00     -0.110 
 5 2019-07-28 00:50:00     -0.511 
 6 2019-07-28 01:00:00     -0.911 
 7 2019-07-28 01:10:00     -0.837 
 8 2019-07-28 01:20:00      2.42  
 9 2019-07-28 01:30:00      0.134 
10 2019-07-28 01:40:00     -0.491
```

Now for the most important moment. We will build a function `f` to modify our internal `tibble` according to your expectations.

```
f = function(data) {
  data$data_sensor[[1]] = data$data_sensor[[1]] %>% mutate(
    date = ifelse(date<data$date_admin, NA, date) %>% as_datetime(),
    Temperature = ifelse(date<data$date_admin, NA, Temperature)
  )  
  data %>% mutate(nNA = sum(is.na(data$data_sensor[[1]]$date)))
}

data_sensor = data_sensor %>% 
  group_by(file) %>% 
  group_modify(~f(.x))

data_sensor$data_sensor
```

output

```
data_sensor$data_sensor
[[1]]
# A tibble: 10 x 2
   date                Temperature
   <dttm>                    <dbl>
 1 2020-10-14 00:10:00      0.314 
 2 2020-10-14 00:20:00      0.359 
 3 2020-10-14 00:30:00     -0.730 
 4 2020-10-14 00:40:00      0.0357
 5 2020-10-14 00:50:00      0.113 
 6 2020-10-14 01:00:00      1.43  
 7 2020-10-14 01:10:00      0.983 
 8 2020-10-14 01:20:00     -0.622 
 9 2020-10-14 01:30:00     -0.732 
10 2020-10-14 01:40:00     -0.517 

[[2]]
# A tibble: 10 x 2
   date   Temperature
   <dttm> <lgl>      
 1 NA     NA         
 2 NA     NA         
 3 NA     NA         
 4 NA     NA         
 5 NA     NA         
 6 NA     NA         
 7 NA     NA         
 8 NA     NA         
 9 NA     NA         
10 NA     NA
```

As you can see, everything works great.
Additionally, our `f` function, apart from the `data_sensor` mutation, returns the number of `NA` observations.

```
# A tibble: 2 x 4
# Groups:   file [2]
  file   date_admin data_sensor         nNA
  <chr>  <chr>      <list>            <int>
1 file 1 2018-10-07 <tibble [10 x 2]>     0
2 file 2 2019-07-29 <tibble [10 x 2]>    10
```

So it's time to test it on a bit bigger data. Here I used your `date_admin` vector and drew 106 `tibbles` each containing 100000 observations!

```
date_admin = c(
  "2018-10-07", "2018-12-29", "2018-12-13", "2019-08-09", "2019-10-10",
  "2019-04-26", "2018-11-21", "2018-08-23", "2019-07-08", "2019-11-19",
  "2019-11-07", "2018-09-05", "2018-09-03", "2018-09-24", "2018-10-11",
  "2018-09-25", "2019-03-29", "2018-08-20", "2018-09-17", "2019-03-30",
  "2018-11-07", "2019-01-01", "2018-08-31", "2019-03-27", "2019-11-10",
  "2019-04-04", "2019-10-18", "2018-09-06", "2018-09-23", "2018-09-22",
  "2019-07-22", "2018-09-04", "2019-05-17", "2018-11-05", "2018-12-09",
  "2018-09-03", "2019-05-21", "2019-02-22", "2018-08-30", "2019-06-04",
  "2018-09-13", "2018-10-14", "2019-11-08", "2018-08-30", "2019-04-12",
  "2018-09-24", "2018-08-22", "2018-08-30", "2018-09-07", "2018-11-11",
  "2018-11-01", "2018-10-01", "2018-10-22", "2018-12-03", "2019-06-06",
  "2018-09-09", "2018-09-10", "2018-09-24", "2018-10-11", "2018-11-30",
  "2018-09-20", "2019-11-20", "2018-10-11", "2018-10-09", "2018-09-27",
  "2019-11-11", "2018-10-04", "2018-09-14", "2019-04-27", "2018-09-04",
  "2018-09-11", "2018-08-14", "2018-09-01", "2018-10-01", "2018-09-25",
  "2018-09-28", "2018-09-29", "2018-10-11", "2019-03-26", "2018-10-26",
  "2018-11-21", "2018-12-02", "2018-09-08", "2019-01-08", "2018-11-07",
  "2019-02-05", "2019-01-21", "2018-09-11", "2018-12-17", "2019-01-15",
  "2018-08-28", "2019-01-08", "2019-05-14", "2019-01-21", "2018-11-12",
  "2018-10-26", "2019-12-26", "2020-01-03", "2020-01-06", "2020-02-26",
  "2020-02-14", "2020-01-27", "2020-01-21", "2020-03-16", "2020-02-26",
  "2019-12-31")

nDateSensor = 100000
set.seed(1234)

data_sensor = 
  tibble(
    file = paste("file",1:length(date_admin)),
    date_admin = date_admin
  ) %>% 
  mutate(data_sensor = map(file, ~fDateSensor(nDateSensor)))
```

output

```
 data_sensor
# A tibble: 106 x 3
   file    date_admin data_sensor           
   <chr>   <chr>      <list>                
 1 file 1  2018-10-07 <tibble [100,000 x 2]>
 2 file 2  2018-12-29 <tibble [100,000 x 2]>
 3 file 3  2018-12-13 <tibble [100,000 x 2]>
 4 file 4  2019-08-09 <tibble [100,000 x 2]>
 5 file 5  2019-10-10 <tibble [100,000 x 2]>
 6 file 6  2019-04-26 <tibble [100,000 x 2]>
 7 file 7  2018-11-21 <tibble [100,000 x 2]>
 8 file 8  2018-08-23 <tibble [100,000 x 2]>
 9 file 9  2019-07-08 <tibble [100,000 x 2]>
10 file 10 2019-11-19 <tibble [100,000 x 2]>
# ... with 96 more rows
```

Time for a mutation. We will immediately measure how long it will take.

```
start_time =Sys.time()
data_sensor = data_sensor %>% 
  group_by(file) %>% 
  group_modify(~f(.x))
Sys.time()-start_time
```

For me it took 2.3 seconds. I don't know if you expected such time but it seems to be quite a good result.
Let's see what our `data_sensor` looks like.

```
# A tibble: 106 x 4
# Groups:   file [106]
   file     date_admin data_sensor              nNA
   <chr>    <chr>      <list>                 <int>
 1 file 1   2018-10-07 <tibble [100,000 x 2]>     0
 2 file 10  2019-11-19 <tibble [100,000 x 2]> 19001
 3 file 100 2020-02-26 <tibble [100,000 x 2]> 95897
 4 file 101 2020-02-14 <tibble [100,000 x 2]>  7769
 5 file 102 2020-01-27 <tibble [100,000 x 2]> 99497
 6 file 103 2020-01-21 <tibble [100,000 x 2]>     0
 7 file 104 2020-03-16 <tibble [100,000 x 2]> 50969
 8 file 105 2020-02-26 <tibble [100,000 x 2]>     0
 9 file 106 2019-12-31 <tibble [100,000 x 2]> 13673
10 file 11  2019-11-07 <tibble [100,000 x 2]> 16697
# ... with 96 more rows
```

As you can see, some of the data has been changed to `NA`. So everything worked fine.
All you have to do is read the xls file names into `data_sensor` and then using`group_by (file)`and `group_modify` to load the data into the variable `data_sensor`. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for this awesome solution!! I am having only one problem: Error in UseMethod("group_by") :    no applicable method for 'group_by' applied to an object of class "list" in the groupby after the function. I think that is beacause my data_sensor is a list of tibbles. If I do the tibbles with internal tibbles, then I get a list of lists. I will add the output in the question to explain myself better.

Comment: Do it this way. 1. Create a `tibble` with one `file` variable and enter the names of all your files. You can use the `dir_ls` function from the `fs` package here. 2. Write a function such as `fReadFile` which will take the file name parameter and return the content read in `tibble` similar to my `fDateSensor`, except that the data will not be randomized but read from the file. Run yours function `mutate (data_sensor = map (file, ~ fReadFile (.x)))`. Let me know if it worked.

Comment: You can also take a look at my other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68981962/loop-on-files-parse-files-and-group-them-by-identifier/68987784?noredirect=1#comment122298401_68987784) where a similar file reading mechanism is made. Mark "This answer is useful" beside it, of course if it is.

Answer (score 1):

If you convert the whole thing in a vectorized sub-setting operation it should be an order of magnitude quicker e.g.:

```r
for (i in seq_along(data_sensor)){
  data_sensor[[i]]<- data_sensor[[i]][as.Date(data_sensor[[i]]$date)<as.Date(date_admin[i]),]
}
```

For loops are generally some what slow it is better to avoid nested loops and use vectorized operations where possible

ps by lack of data I could not try this

Comment: Even with the lack of data you have seen it and it works pretty fast! Thank you @Bart!!